# Scrapy - how do I load data from the database in ItemLoader before sending it to the pipeline?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a PSQL database table `brands` where are columns like `id`, `name`, and other columns.

My (simplified) code - `MySpider.py`:

```
import DB

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  db = DB.connect()
  def start_requests(self):
    urls = [ 'https://www.website.com']
    for url in URLs:
      yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta=meta)    

  def parse(self, response):
    cars = response.css('...')
    for car in cars:
      item = CarLoader(item=Car(), selector=car)
      data.add_value('brand_id', car.css('...').get())
      ...
```

`items.py`:

```
import scrapy
class Car(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    brand_id = scrapy.Field()
    established = scrapy.Field()
    ...
```

`itemsloaders.py`:

```
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class CarLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

When I am saving a new item to the database (that's done in `pipeline.py`), I don't want to save to the column `cars.brand_id` the brand name (BMW, Audi, etc.) of the car, but its ID (this ID is stored in `brands.id`).

What's the proper way of doing that? I need to search the name of the brand in the `brands` table and the found ID save to `cars.brand_id` - but where should I place this operation, so it's logical and scrappy-correct?

I was thinking and doing that in `MySpider.py`, as well as in `pipeline.py`, but I find it a bit dirty and it does not feel it belongs there.

It seems that this functionality should be placed to `itemsloaders.py`, but the purpose of this file is a bit mystical to me. How do I resolve this?

Comment: If the spider doesn't know IDs in your database (which it shouldn't) this is not a Scrapy-related question, you need to do DB queries before saving the data to the DB.

Comment: Alternatively, if the `brands` table doesn't change, load it once somewhere in the pipeline's initialization code and access that before saving the data to the DB.